# 'recently' in past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect

Can 'recently' mean *not long before a specific time in the past*?

For example, is it correct to say the following sentence?

> That day, when Jim arrived home, he started eating the ice cream he had recently bought.

If not, what adverbs or phrases best suit here?

Comment: Given the relatively short lifetime of ice cream, ***recently*** probably isn't a good choice of adverb there. You wouldn't normally say *I recently bought X* if you'd actually bought X earlier that day - when referring to actions completed a *very* short time ago, it's more natural to say something like *I [have] [only] **just** bought it*. But in your case it's contextually obvious Jim couldn't have bought the ice cream very long before arriving home, so there's no real point in trying to convey that explicitly - you might as well have said *he started eating the ice cream he [had] bought*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, maybe he bought the ice cream two days before and has kept it in the freezer since then?

Comment: @The Photon: Bizarrely, if I didn't know the text came from a non-native speaker, I'd say your (superficially, *contrived*) interpretation is far more likely than that John ate the ice-cream on the same day he bought it. Which just goes to show that *recently* doesn't usually work when the sense is *earlier that day* (I'd say it nearly always implies *not long before that day*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, agreed, I didn't even think that the OP might have meant the ice cream was bought earlier that day until you commented.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks for your comment. I see what you mean. But the main point of my question is something else. That sentence is just an example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Why are you talking about "on the same day"? OP asks about "not long before".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Well, OP hasn't *explicitly* confirmed my suspicions, but it still seems to me he was talking about the ice-cream John had *brought home with him* (i.e. - ***bought** earlier that day*). And since so far as I'm concerned, the question is about how to use the word ***recently***, I think it's relevant to point out that although the cited example is *grammatical*, it probably won't be understood as havging the meaning OP intends. Note that *not long before* implies nothing as regards "on an earlier day" or "earlier that day".

Comment: *Note that not long before implies nothing as regards "on an earlier day" or "earlier that day"*.  Exactly. That's why I'm wondering why you have your "suspicions" that OP was taking about "earlier that day".  I believe OP has indicated, in his last comment, that the same day is not what he was implying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22had%20only%20recently%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), **recently** can be relative to an explicit or implicit reference time in the past.

> When the Little-Endians lay siege to the city in 1524, their numbers included
>   mercenary troops they had recently hired from Freedonia.

Comment: Reason for the downvote, please.

Comment: I suspect either a programmer who objects to your expropriation of a term of art and its use in a whimsical connexion, or a Fredonian who objects to the misplelling of the name of Die Vaterland.

Comment: @P.E. Dant. Sir, no one accuses me of whimsy. Soft boiled eggs at dawn.

Comment: ...and two duck eggs.